# Qatar issue impact on Bahrain

Tags: bahrain

I got a job offer from Bahrain and will be moving there in another 50 odd days. Just would like to know if the recent Qatar issue has had any negative impact on Bahrain that an expat should be concerned of?

Answer (score 1):

In one word.. No.. Other than if you want to travel between the nations, that would be hard. [Baharain-Qatar relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahrain%E2%80%93Qatar_relations)

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this, especially your caveat, as it is a rather critical and delicate situation.